# Function for calculating Archimedean density functions

Tags: performance, r, rcpp

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this, so please correct me if it's not.

I am following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.6032.pdf) (e.g., Corollary 3.3) for some derived functional representations of the densities and writing code for those. The code for one of the families:

(`x` will be a vector of 1xd between [0,1], `tau` - scalar in [1, infty).)

```
'joe_density' <- function(x, tau){
  require(gmp)
  require(Rmpfr)
  require(magrittr)

  d <- length(x)

  P_d <- function(x, tau, d){
    alpha <- 1/tau
    lapply(1:d, function(k){
      as.numeric(gmp::Stirling2(n = d, k = k)) * gamma(k - alpha) / gamma(1 - alpha) * x^(k-1)
    }) %>% do.call(sum, .)
  }

  h <- prod((1 - (1 - x)^tau))

  mpfr( tau^(d-1), 16) * 
    mpfr( prod((1 - x)^(tau - 1)), 16) / 
    mpfr( (1 - h)^(1 - 1/tau), 16) * 
    mpfr( P_d( h/(1-h), tau, d), 16)
}
```

Example call:

```
# Simple case
x <- pnorm(rnorm(100))
joe_density(x, tau = 2)

# Longer performance time when looping, d=2
expand.grid(x = seq(-5,5,by=0.1), y = seq(-5,5,by=0.1)) %>%
  apply(.,1,function(z){
     x <- pnorm(z)
     joe_density(x, tau = 2)
  })
```

In essence, the typical calculations require tons of looping, gamma/Stirling numbers, and I have noticed that the default precision is usually not enough, hence the `Rmpfr` usage. One time evaluation of the code is not a problem, however, the calculations become very lengthy when the function is called thousands of time (e.g., passing it to  `optim` and the likes).

Are there simpler ways to program this? This particular function is just an example, but most of the different functions follow similar approach, with a high usage of Stirling/gamma, lengthy products and etc.

Could, for example, rewriting parts of the code in `Rcpp` be helpful, or is this not the type of task that we could expect  gains here? I have no experience in writing `cpp` code, so am not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- split code more, line by line, so it is easier to profile and see bottlenecks
- use `profvis`
- use `%>%` less often if that part of code is called frequently, it has some overhead
- separate function definitions

This should run a little bit faster: (15s vs 27s on your example)

```
P_d <- function(x, tau, d){
  alpha <- 1/tau
  l <- sapply(1:d, function(k){
    p1 <- Stirling2(n = d, k = k)
    p1 <- as.numeric(p1)
    p1 * gamma(k - alpha) / gamma(1 - alpha) * x^(k-1)
  })
  sum(l)
}

joe_density <- function(x, tau){
  d <- length(x)
  h <- prod((1 - (1 - x)^tau))

  v1 <- tau^(d-1)
  v2 <- prod((1 - x)^(tau - 1))
  v3 <- (1 - h)^(1 - 1/tau)
  v4 <- P_d( h/(1-h), tau, d)

  p1 <- mpfr(v1, 16) # slow
  p1 * v2 / v3 * v4 # slow
}
```

The slowest part is `mpfr` & the last line, because each value is converted to `mpfr`.
Maybe you can deal with precision loss in some kind of different way?

Comment: Thanks, all very good points! Will add ``profvis``  to the toolbox, looks promising. For larger dimensions, ``Stirling2`` seems to be the largest bottleneck, as can be expected. About the ``mpfr`` - will have to test when can I really drop it; it was added to deal with extreme numeric values, both explosive and very close to 0, but maybe some approximations at both ends will work too.